# reactjs clear file input field after submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm trying to delete my file input field data from e.target but i need the rest of the e.target data to send to emailjs.

The problem is when user uploads a file in my form, the file is most of the time bigger than 50kb and this is the limit for my account on emailjs.

I don't need to send my file to emailjs but i need it to just be stored in my database.

I have tried to clear the form field before sending it to emailjs
with `fileUpload.current.value = "";` but the data is still actief in
e.target.

This is e.target Data. i need the data to stay in this way in e.target to send to emailjs

```
<form class="Grade_inputForm__1lbhQ" autocomplete="off">
<div class="Grade_input_container__3ztZk css-vurnku">
<input type="text" name="name" required="" class="Grade_input__22PTE" placeholder="Name*" maxlength="10">
</div>
<div class="Grade_input_container__3ztZk css-vurnku">
<input type="email" required="" name="email" class="Grade_input__22PTE" placeholder="Email*">
</div>
<div class="Grade_input_container__3ztZk css-vurnku">
<input type="text" name="Address" required="" class="Grade_input__22PTE" placeholder="Address*">
</div>
<div class="Grade_input_container__3ztZk css-vurnku">
<input type="tel" name="phone" class="Grade_input__22PTE" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
<div class="Grade_input_container__3ztZk css-vurnku">
<input type="file" class="Grade_input__22PTE" name="5349366.jpg">
</div>
<div class="Grade_textarea__YR0na css-vurnku">
<textarea name="cards" required="" class="Grade_input__22PTE">
</textarea>
</div>
<div class="Grade_textarea__YR0na css-vurnku">
<textarea name="message" class="Grade_input__22PTE" placeholder="Message">
</textarea>
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="Grade_btn__1QKUn">
</form>
```

how can i delete my file from e.target ?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { jsx, Box } from "theme-ui";
import style from "../../style/Grade.module.css";
import { db, storage } from "../components/config/config";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";

export default function GradeCards() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const name = useRef("");
  const email = useRef("");
  const Addres = useRef("");
  const phone = useRef("");
  const cards = useRef("");
  const message = useRef("");
  const fileUpload = useRef("");

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //sending data to emailjs with e.target
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "service account",
        "template name",
        e.target, 
        "user_id"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };

  const sendDataToDb = (e) => {
    // sendEmail(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist(); // this is test when i use sendEmail() in .then()

    const formData = new FormData(e.target);

    const obj = {};
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      obj[key] = value;
    }

    if (file !== null) {
      storage
        .ref(`/files/${Date.now() + "-" + file.name}`)
        .put(file)
        .then(() => console.log("Succes"));
    }

    //this don't help in deleting data from e.target
    delete obj[file.name];

    db.collection("collectionName")
      .add(obj)
      .then(() => {
        fileUpload.current.value = "";
      })
      .then(() => {
        //test if the data is deleted her.But its still actief in e.target
        console.log(e.target);
        sendEmail(e);
      })
      .then(() => {
        name.current.value = "";
        email.current.value = "";
        Addres.current.value = "";
        phone.current.value = "";
        cards.current.value = "";
        message.current.value = "";
        console.log("done sending");
      });
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <Box className={style.container}>
        <Box className={style.form}>
          <Box className={style.contact_form}>
            <form
              onSubmit={(e) => sendDataToDb(e)}
              className={style.inputForm}
              autoComplete="off"
            >              
              <Box className={style.input_container}>
                <input
                  ref={name}
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  required
                  className={style.input}
                  placeholder="Name*"
                  maxLength="10"
                />
              </Box>
              <Box className={style.input_container}>
                <input
                  ref={email}
                  type="email"
                  required
                  name="email"
                  className={style.input}
                  placeholder="Email*"
                />
              </Box>
              <Box className={style.input_container}>
                <input
                  ref={Addres}
                  type="text"
                  name="Address"
                  required
                  className={style.input}
                  placeholder="Address*"
                />
              </Box>
              <Box className={style.input_container}>
                <input
                  ref={phone}
                  type="tel"
                  name="phone"
                  className={style.input}
                  placeholder="Phone"
                />
              </Box>
              <Box className={style.input_container}>                
                <input
                  ref={fileUpload}
                  type="file"
                  name={file?.name}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
                  }}
                  className={style.input}
                />
              </Box>
              <Box className={(style.input_container, style.textarea)}>
                <textarea
                  ref={cards}
                  name="cards"
                  required
                  className={style.input}                 
                ></textarea>
              </Box>
              <Box className={(style.input_container, style.textarea)}>
                <textarea
                  ref={message}
                  name="message"
                  className={style.input}
                  placeholder="Message"
                ></textarea>
              </Box>
              <br />
              <input type="submit" value="Send" className={style.btn} />
            </form>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you can set it here, but in general, if you have an input of type `file` and with name let's say `image2`, then you can do the following:

```
e.target["image2"].value = [];
```

this will empty the input.

See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-file-upload-forked-3dmkn)

If you comment out the previous line of code, it will display the full details of the chosen file.
If you have this line there, it will display the object as it was never assigned a file from your disk.

Comment: cool thanks this is wat i was looking for. One Love